# In a div that has overflow:scroll, how do I check what position the scroll is at?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using JQuery.

How do I know if it's scrolled to the middle? Top? Bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the element's `scrollLeft`, `scrollTop`, `scrollWidth` and `scrollHeight` properties to find out the status of the element's scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will allow you to get `scrollTop` property like an attribute...

```
$('element').attr('scrollTop');
```

Answer (score 0):

> scrollTop gets or sets the number of
>   pixels that the content of an element
>   is scrolled upward

[MDC Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollTop)